# Single key & multiple values without using multimap - Java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

How can I store multiple values against single key in java , without using a hashmap or multi-map. Any one knows how to do it using arrays only?

eg:

```
Key : Id
Value   : a , b, c, d
```

So instead of storing above as `Id a , Id b ,Id c` etc

I want to store it as `Id "a,b,c,d"` . Ie one key against multiple values in the form of string .

So I don't want to use any multimap or hashmap for this.

Comment: Why not a `HashMap`?  A `HashMap` with its value type as an array (or a `List`) sounds like a good choice.

Comment: What's the reason for not using a HashMap or a Multimap? And what have you tried?

Comment: I smell a homework question..

Comment: A 2D array, but Map provides better look up mechanism

Comment: A hashmap is perfect for this. You can always just use two arrays like a hashmap but this is exactly where you'd want to use one.

Comment: You could use a `TreeMap<String, List<Id>>` but it is hard to know what to suggest if you can't use the obvious and simplest options.

Comment: Dictionary<string,List<string>> myDict;

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a multi map or a a hashmap and want to use an array, use a binary tree. Each node will be a key and the values of the node will be a linked list.

Any non-hashmap construct will however not give you a O(1) return time. You can use a binary tree or a Trie, dependeing on what your Id is (whether it is a string or an int). For a Trie, lookup will be O(k) ~` O(1), but it works better with strings.

IF you are not using a hashmap however , this is an inefiicient solution . It seems you have been asked this in an interview / online chalenge which tests your understanding of datastructures.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful for someone who is looking for a solution
Using Java HashMap:

```
if (myMap.get(key) == null) {
                myMap.put(key, value);
            } else
                myMap.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + value);
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like an answer to this question.

Comment: Multiple values can be concatenated as a string as per your requirement